# Selenium XPATH or CSS to select a checkbox with the specified text from a html table I am getting two checkboxes selected

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select a checkbox from a HTML table of columns.  I would like to select the checkbox which has the text "USN"
My XPATH is selecting 2 checkboxes:

- USN
- USN Date

I would like to select the 1 checkbox:

- USN

My XPATH is:

```
//table[@id="reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_fields_avail"]//div[contains(text(), "USN")]/preceding::td[1]//input
```

How do i build my XPATH or CSS to select the exact checkbox i want?
And also in case if the structure changes the XPATH or CSS is robust.

The HTML is:

```
<table id="reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_fields_avail" class="GLKP2TGBJE" cellspacing="0" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus="true" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingblur="true">
<thead aria-hidden="false">
    <colgroup>
        <tbody style="">
            <tr class="GLKP2TGBCD GLKP2TGBJD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBED GLKP2TGBKD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-500" style="outline-style:none;">
                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBKD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-501" style="outline-style:none;">USN</div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBOD GLKP2TGBKD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-502" style="outline-style:none;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="GLKP2TGBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE GLKP2TGBED">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-500" style="outline-style:none;">
                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-501" style="outline-style:none;">DATASET</div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE GLKP2TGBOD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-502" style="outline-style:none;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="GLKP2TGBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="2">
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBED">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-500" style="outline-style:none;">
                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-501" style="outline-style:none;">ID</div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBOD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-502" style="outline-style:none;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="GLKP2TGBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="3">
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE GLKP2TGBED">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-500" style="outline-style:none;">
                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-501" style="outline-style:none;">MATCH_AUDIT</div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE GLKP2TGBOD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-502" style="outline-style:none;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="GLKP2TGBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="4">
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBED">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-500" style="outline-style:none;">
                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-501" style="outline-style:none;">EXPANDED_MATCH_AUDIT</div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBOD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-502" style="outline-style:none;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="GLKP2TGBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="5">
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE GLKP2TGBED">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-500" style="outline-style:none;">
                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-501" style="outline-style:none;">INTERNAL_ID</div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE GLKP2TGBOD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-502" style="outline-style:none;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="GLKP2TGBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="6">
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBED">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-500" style="outline-style:none;">
                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-501" style="outline-style:none;">USN_DATE</div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBOD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-502" style="outline-style:none;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="GLKP2TGBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="7">
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE GLKP2TGBED">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-500" style="outline-style:none;">
                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-501" style="outline-style:none;">VERSION</div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE GLKP2TGBOD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-502" style="outline-style:none;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="GLKP2TGBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="8">
                <tr class="GLKP2TGBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="9">
                    <tr class="GLKP2TGBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="10">
        </tbody>
        <tbody style="display: none;">
            <tfoot style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true" />
```

Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//*[text() = 'USN']
```

This xpath will work but this one is a long query .. Try to use `text()= 'USN'` this along with yours instead of contains.

Comment: That's great.  Got it.  Thank you.

Comment: For the interest of others whom come accross this question.  The XPATH i now use is //table[@id="reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_fields_avail"]//div[(text()="USN")]/preceding::td[1]//input